# Talend Remote server mysql database connection

Tags: mysql, etl, talend, remote-server

I have been assigned ETL tasks using talend and have been very impressed with the capabilities of the tool.  One common need that I have will be accessing remote MySQL Databases via port forwarding / tunneling. how to do it using Talend? does anyone done it before?

Comment: you can use tMySqlConnection component to connect to MySQL database

Comment: i tried that, it throws following error -- https://prnt.sc/gk5s99

Comment: can you please share error log stack trace

Comment: @PreetyK : how can i get error log stack? you mean terminal?

Comment: yes..please share screenshot of job and error log from talend console

Comment: PreetyK: please find Component --> https://prnt.sc/gk5vze  
 and job and error --> https://prnt.sc/gk5w99. Sorry i'm new to talend if something is wrong please let me know.

Comment: Is the host you are providing is correct?

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/154225/discussion-between-preetyk-and-harish-sng).